# Changing search button color

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I created a custom.css file and i added this code:

```
#search_mini_form .search-button {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 0;
  background: #F62817;
}
```

but the color won't change. What else do i need to do?

local.xml

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name></action>
```

Comment: Just check if your css file is loading at all. If yes open the file through browser by hitting the file url and check if your code is there. If yes then either your selectors may not working or your code is not there or your file is not loaded.

Comment: Where do you have put your custom.css, the path ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check weather your CSS is included or not. I think this xml code will help you to include CSS

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
```

Then apply your CSS code like

```
#search_mini_form .search-button {
  background: #ccccc;
}
```

Comment: addCss or addItem is the same think